# How do I update a backreference inline in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, grouping, backreference, inline-code

Given the following code:

```
alpha = ('"foo"="bar"').replace(/.*foo...([^"]*).*/, RegExp.$1)
beta = ('"bar"="baz"').replace(/.*bar...([^"]*).*/, RegExp.$1)
```

The expected output is:

```
alpha is "bar"
beta is "bar"
```

The actual output is:

```
alpha is ""
beta is "bar"
```

Which led me to this workaround:

```js
var alpha = beta = "", n = "\n";

    ('"foo"="bar"').match(/.*foo...([^"]*).*/);
    alpha.toString.v1 = ('"foo"="bar"').replace(/.*foo...([^"]*).*/, RegExp.$1)

    String('"bar"="baz"').replace(/.*bar...([^"]*).*/);
    beta.toString.v2 = ('"foo"="baz"').replace(/.*foo...([^"]*).*/, RegExp.$1)

    
    document.body.innerText += alpha.toString.v1 + n + alpha.toString.v2;
```

How do I do this without needing the match to update the backreference?

Comment: How about taking advantage of the fact that inside a replacement **string**, `$1`, `$2`, etc. refer to the match groups?

Comment: Also it would help a lot if you could clarify exactly what you **want** the result to be from a given input.

Comment: I tried `$1`, but it's `"$1"`. So `('"foo"="bar"').replace(/.*foo...([^"]*).*/, "$1")` works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use either:

```
// $1 = first backref, $2 = 2nd on through $9
// (*)I'm not sure but I think "$10" gets replaced with "backref1"+"0"
alpha = subject.replace(regex, "$1 $2 ... $N");
```

**: after a bit of testing, it depends on what's matched. If there is a backref after the 9th, the correct backref will be returned. BUT if the backref doesn't exist, it will preform as stated above: "backref1" + "0"*

or:

```
alpha = subject.replace(regex, function(matchedText, backref1, backref2, ...) {
    return "replacement text";
});
```

If you are attempting to get an attribute value match:

```
alpha = '"foo"="bar"'.replace(/"([^"]+)"="([^"]*)"/g, function(matched, attr, value) {
    // matched = "foo"="bar"
    // attr = foo
    // value = bar
});
```

If this is being done within a browser, to get attributes from elements already on the page, I strongly suggest using built-in DOM manipulation handlers.